# A vector that is parallel to a plane and perpendicular to line joining A and B on the plane

Tags: vectors

The equation of the plane is $ \vec r\cdot ( 4 , -33 , -11 ) = 89$
The line AB is $\vec r=(3,-2,-1) + a(-13,-2,-7)$ which is on the plane.

How can I find a vector which is parallel to the plane and perpendicular to the line which is also on the plane?

Comment: Is my edit correct?

Comment: It is not the same r as the r in the equation of the plane is any random point on it. So I think that r in the equation would be (3, -2,-1)  rather than the whole line

Comment: In the equation $\vec r$ is the generic point of the line that passes thorough  $(3,-2,-1)$ and is parallel to the vector $(-13,-2,-7)$.Isn't this  this that you want?

Comment: I need to find another vector which doesn't have to be contained on the plane but it is perpendicular to the line which is contained on the plane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

if $\vec v=(4,-33,-11)^T$ is the vector orthogonal to the plane and $\vec u=(-13,-2,-7)^T $ is the orienting vector of the line than $\vec w=\vec v \times \vec u$ is orthogonal to $\vec v$ (os parallel to the plane) and orthogonal to $\vec u$.

Comment: Is that the dot product? Should that give an answer of a zero because v and u are perpendicular to each other?

Comment: No. It is the **cross product** that gives a vector orthogonal to the two starting vectors . If  you don't know it see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: So I have to cross v with u instead of dotting them together to get the answer w? I'm very sorry but I'm a slow learner! If you want I can send you the whole question.

Comment: Yes, the cross product is the vector that you need.

Comment: I managed to work it out! W (209,171,421) I was not able to picture it well so I couldn't understand why the cross product was being used! Thanks for your help :)